# cannot update string in QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qstring, qtablewidgetitem

I want to change for example 2.16 into 2,16 in a table. This is my code

```
{
    .......
    connect(ui.tableWidget, SIGNAL(itemChanged(QTableWidgetItem*)), this, SLOT(change_string(QTableWidgetItem*)));
}

void MyClass::change_string(QTableWidgetItem* input_item)
{
    if (input_item->text() != "") {
        if (input_item->text().contains(".", Qt::CaseSensitive)) {
            input_item->text().replace(".", ",", Qt::CaseSensitive);
        }
    }
}
```

My code run normally, I have debugged, the line `input_item->text().replace(".", ",", Qt::CaseSensitive);` is implemented. But after that, the table still shows 2.16, not 2,16. I don't know why? Do I need to refresh table or something like that after replacing the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't `setText` in your code. Try this:

```
QString text = input_item->text().replace(".", ",", Qt::CaseSensitive);
input_item->setText(text);
```